# Accessing shapes parameters in plotly interactive args

Tags: python-2.7, plotly

I'm trying to add an interactive shape (circle) to a set of subplots (for simplicity, below I use only one empty plot to create a simple reproducible example).

Intended behaviour of the code below is to be able to switch between two different circles using a drop down menu.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import tools

# Create empty plot to put shapes into
scatter = go.Scatter()
fig = tools.make_subplots(cols=1)
fig.append_trace(scatter, 1, 1)

# Create two different shapes to select from
fig['layout']['shapes'].append(
        {
            'type': 'circle',
            'xref': 'x', 'yref': 'y',
            'x0': 0, 'y0': 0, 'x1': 1, 'y1': 1,
            'visible':True
        })

fig['layout']['shapes'].append(
        {
            'type': 'circle',
            'xref': 'x', 'yref': 'y',
            'x0': 0, 'y0': 0, 'x1': 0.5, 'y1': 0.5,
            'visible':False
        })

# This doesn't work
fig['layout']['updatemenus'] = 
    [{
        x:-0.05, y:0.8,
        buttons=[
            {args:['layout.shapes.visible', [True, False]], label:'1', method:'restyle'},
            {args:['layout.shapes.visible', [False, True]], label:'2', method:'restyle'}
        ]
    }]


py.plot(fig, filename='shape_select')
```

I assume my mistake is that I refer to `visible` parameter in a wrong way, and `layout.shapes.visible` should be replaced with something else.

So, how do I properly refer to shape parameters in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either I am too stupid to find the obvious solution, but this seems like a like a bug or unspecified behavior to me.

The last 8 drop down items reliably work. The first 8 have some unspecified behavior depending on the order they are clicked and might interfere one with another..

The suggested solution uses argument unpacking to create the dictionaries for the shapes on the fly and setting `visible` for each shape.

```
import plotly

shape1 = {
            'type': 'circle',
            'xref': 'x', 'yref': 'y',
            'x0': 0, 'y0': 0, 'x1': 1, 'y1': 1,
            'line': {'color': 'rgb(0, 0, 255)'}
        }
shape2 = {
            'type': 'circle',
            'xref': 'x', 'yref': 'y',
            'x0': 0, 'y0': 0, 'x1': 0.5, 'y1': 0.5,
            'line': {'color': 'rgb(255, 0, 255)'}
        }

trace0 = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
    x= [0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2],
    y= [0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 0.3, 0.2]
)

data = plotly.graph_objs.Data([trace0])
layout = plotly.graph_objs.Layout(shapes=[shape1, shape2])
fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
fig['layout']['shapes'].append(dict(visible=True, **shape1))
fig['layout']['shapes'].append(dict(visible=True, **shape2))


fig['layout']['updatemenus'] = [dict(
        x=-0.05, y=0.8,
        buttons=[
            dict(args=['shapes.visible', [False, True]], label='Hide big - does not work', method='relayout'),
            dict(args=['shapes.visible', [True, False]], label='Hide small - does not work', method='relayout'),
            dict(args=['shapes[0].visible', False], label='Hide big - might work', method='relayout'),
            dict(args=['shapes[1].visible', False], label='Hide small - might work', method='relayout'),
            dict(args=['shapes[0].visible', True], label='Show big', method='relayout'),
            dict(args=['shapes[1].visible', True], label='Show small', method='relayout'),
            dict(args=['shapes', [dict(visible=True, **shape1), dict(visible=True, **shape2)]], label='Show all', method='relayout'),
            dict(args=['shapes', [dict(visible=False, **shape1), dict(visible=False, **shape2)]], label='Hide all', method='relayout'),
            dict(args=['shapes', [dict(visible=True, **shape1), dict(visible=False, **shape2)]], label='Show big, hide small', method='relayout'),
            dict(args=['shapes', [dict(visible=False, **shape1), dict(visible=True, **shape2)]], label='Hide big, show small', method='relayout')
        ]
    )]

plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='shape_select.html')
```

Comment: Thank you, the last two lines are working as expected! Yes, I did try the first option first thing and was also surprised it didn't work...

Comment: Another stupid question :) What if I want to pass several arguments? That is, with one dropdown change both shapes and data for scatter, how would I do it? Seems like something obvious, but can't find it in examples and `args=['shapes', [...], 'visible', [True, False]] ` seem to just break the whole thing... I can post it separately...

Comment: (each of the switches works separately, I just wonder how to put two of them in the same button)

Comment: I would put it in the Javascript code, easier to control and it does work reliably.

Answer (score 2):

This a bit more compact solution works as well:

```
fig['layout']['updatemenus'] = [dict(
    x=-0.05, y=0.8,
        dict(args=[{'shapes[0].visible': True, 'shapes[1].visible': False}], label='First circle', method='relayout'),
        dict(args=[{'shapes[0].visible': False, 'shapes[1].visible': True}], label='First circle', method='relayout'),
    ]
)]
```